# How to get the response from Azure Data Lake Rest API using Azure API Management?

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-api-management

I want to make a call to the Azure Data Lake Gen 1 using Data Lake rest API. I tried making the call through Javascript but because I ran into CORS, I decided to have a layer between JS and ADLS using Azure API Management. So basically a user would call the APIM and the APIM internally would call the ADLS Rest API and send me the response. Using the CURL command as reference,

```
curl -X POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT-ID>/oauth2/token  \
  -F grant_type=client_credentials \
  -F resource=https://management.core.windows.net/ \
  -F client_id=<CLIENT-ID> \
  -F client_secret=<AUTH-KEY>
```

I am trying to fetch the OAuth Token from ADLS using APIM. This is what I have so far,

The APIM Policies :

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-method>POST</set-method>
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"</value>
        </set-header>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <set-body>{
            'grant_type':'client_credentials',
            'resource':'https://management.core.windows.net/',
            'client_id':'#################################',
            'client_secret':'#######################'    
            }</set-body>
    </backend>
    <outbound>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

I can successfully make a call to the ADLS but how do I consume the response from APIM that is the OAuth token and route it to my caller in APIM?

Comment: Do you want APIM to talk to ADLS or just get you a token?

Comment: So I basically want to perform filesystem operations with ADLS .For that I need to get the token from ADLS and pass it back to JS through APIM.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you configured your API you may also need to add rewrite-uri and/or set-backend-service into inbound to direct call to https://login.microsoftonline.com.

Otherwise try:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-method>POST</set-method>
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body>{
            'grant_type':'client_credentials',
            'resource':'https://management.core.windows.net/',
            'client_id':'#################################',
            'client_secret':'#######################'    
            }</set-body>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <forward-request/>
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Comment: This is not working. It sets up the body of the inbound request but when the body of the backend is still empty.